# GLTF export location offset error

Tags: error, three.js, gltf

I have to make a WebGL page to display an animation importing a character that someone else created for a "normal" animation (for video). I'm using three.js GLTF and Blender 2.8 combination to achieve my goals. This is the procedure I'm implementing and it works like a charm:

1. Import object from blend file #1 to blend file #2.
2. Ctrl+A to apply all transformations.
3. Animate
4. Bake animation
5. Make animation linear
6. Push action to NLA

This works 100% of the time but with this imported model I get a location offset in my web canvas. After over 12 hours of testing and looking up information about this behavior the only solution was to make a new object and associate the imported mesh and get rid of the imported object.
Here is a *[Shared Folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h201r3tgqv1cw7o/AADp5EMvqXG8o2gJFUhqJcGSa?dl=0)*
 containing the Blend and exported GLB file, where the object "body" is the one with problems and the object "suzanne" is the error free object. Both share mesh and action.

So my QUESTION IS:
Does anyone knows what is going on with this object?

Cheers.

Comment: Forgot to mention the original model was made in a  Blender  version earlier than 2.8.

Comment: It would probably be worth testing this on a recent version of Blender. If the problem is still there, you can file a bug on https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO.